# Check whether a no has exactly two Prime Factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Is there a way to check whether an integer has exactly two prime factors(can be same) that is , it can be expressed as a product of two prime nos ?

EDIT: I dont want to find the factors i just want a formulae or an algo to check whether a certain no can be expressed as a product of two primes either true or false.

NOTE: The supposed existing answer doesn't answer this at all.

Comment: So we have fast (that is, not requiring factorization) ways to check whether a given number is prime, and you want a fast way to check whether it is _semiprime_. That's a reasonable question, but, AFAIK, the answer is negative.

Comment: I didn't get it, how much time would it take to write _algorithm_ instead of "algo" ?

Comment: There is no known efficient way to find that out. But surprisingly there are numbers known to be semiprimes without known factors. Such a number was constructed with the help of elliptic curves. The factors might never be found, but it can be proven that the number is a product of exactly two primes.

Comment: You use the Dirichlet convolution of the characteristic function for the set of primes through itself.

Comment: then n is the independent variable and the function gives 1 if the number has two prime factors and 0 if the number does not have two prime factors.  Note those are factors and not divisors.